# How to save multiple csv files in different folders with R's purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

how could I save multiple csv files in different folders with R's purrr::map out of this tibble? 
The files in column `nested_tbl` should be saved in `file_path`.

```
   file_path                                                                                            nested_tbl             
   <chr>                                                                                                <named list>           
 1 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADR2.csv         <tibble [1,923 x 17]>  
 2 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADR2_ZFIRMEN.csv <tibble [832 x 17]>    
 3 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADR3.csv         <tibble [34 x 18]>     
 4 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADR3_ZFIRMEN.csv <tibble [800 x 18]>    
 5 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADR6.csv         <tibble [462 x 16]>    
 6 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADR6_ZFIRMEN.csv <tibble [472 x 16]>    
 7 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADRC.csv         <tibble [6,082 x 99]>  
 8 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/ADRC_ZFIRMEN.csv <tibble [890 x 100]>   
 9 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/AFIH.csv         <tibble [10,642 x 46]> 
10 C:/02_Testumgebung/wrw-data-analysis/1_Analysis/Daten/_WrW_Gruppe_Daten/WrW_SAP_P17/AUFK.csv         <tibble [10,642 x 120]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` in base R :

```
Map(write.csv, data$nested_tbl, data$file_path)
```

Or if you want to use `purrr` :

```
purrr::map2(data$nested_tbl, data$file_path, write_csv)
```